# Disable browsable click for android auto media app

Tags: android, media-player, android-auto

I'm developing the android auto streaming app(media support), in which I want to display the program list

I have displayed the program by giving the flag `MediaItem.FLAG_BROWSABLE` into `MediaMetadataCompat.Builder` and attach it to the root list

like below

```
MediaMetadataCompat.Builder().apply {
                        id = "program"
                        displayTitle = "program name"                          
                        flag = MediaItem.FLAG_BROWSABLE
                    }.build()
```

My question is can I disable the click of the `MediaItem.FLAG_BROWSABLE` list?

I have tried

1. [onLoadChildren](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-app/building-a-mediabrowserservice#communicating_content_with_onloadchildren) method check if parentMediaId match to the id then return the function and not allow browsing
2. Tried not giving id into `MediaMetadataCompat.Builder()`, but it crashes the app
   error is `description must have a non-empty media id`

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: No, I haven't figured it out @Starwave

Comment: what do you want to achieve with that? Not browsing means playing, then you have to use `MediaItem.FLAG_PLAYABLE`